# iOS app picks up secondary language or Spanish as the main language even though phone's primary language is English

Tags: ios, react-native

I am having a strange bug where in iOS is picking up the second preferred language on the phone as the main language and showing the strings in that language. I use `react-native` and it started to happen after I upgraded to `0.64.0`. For example, in the below screenshot, the month strings are shown in Hindi. Hindi is the second preferred language on the phone.

[image]

The `Cancel` and `Select` buttons are added by JS side code which appears fine in English language. After I removed Hindi as the second preferred language leaving only English as the phone language, the month string started to appear in Spanish.

[image]

I am not sure what is triggering it and how to fix this problem. Any kind of help is much appreciated. I provide Hindi and Spanish translations for the app and have InfoPlist.strings file present for Hindi and Spanish in the app. If I remove those string files, then the strings are shown in English as expected.

**Please note that the problem is not limited to the date picker. It is for any of the dialogs shown by iOS. For example, if I select any text, the copy label appears in Spanish.** I have attached some other screenshots where the problem can be seen.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: 1. Which library you are using for showing the date/month/year?
2. Are you using any kind of multi-language support system on your app?

Comment: I am using the default `@react-native-community/datetimepicker` to show the date picker which internally uses the date picker provided by iOS. The app is provided in multiple languages. The JS side showing the right strings. It is just the iOS native strings are in the secondary language when I haven't even picked that language on the iPhone.

Comment: may be you need to set the locale of datetimepicker

Comment: @Sujit As I have mentioned in the question, date picker is just an example. It is happening for all the native dialogs.

Comment: I think it might be helpful if you provide some way to regenerate this issue. Some minimal code example or expo snack, whichever generates that error.

Comment: can you try changing your region to US?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Settings app.
Navigate to a--name > Preferred Language > Language.
Change the preferred language to Spanish.

also try setting the preferred language to just English and forget the Hindi and let us know what happens. also good chance this might fix you up:https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs